# Help with Cross-Domain file for ActionScript 3 Socket

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, sockets, crossdomain.xml

Here is My ActionScript Code:

```
  var S:Socket=new Socket("127.0.0.1",2222);
```

Here is My CrossDomain.XML File (Located at http://127.0.0.1/crossdomain.xml)

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
  <cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="2222"/>
  </cross-domain-policy>
```

Here is The Error I Am Getting

```
  Ignoring policy file at xmlsocket://127.0.0.1:2222 due to incorrect syntax.
```

Having never used one before, I don't understand what's wrong with the syntax of my CrossDomain file.

Please Help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Socket policy files work a little differently than HTTP policy files; in particular, they aren't served via HTTP, or at port 80.

Instead, Flash Player checks for a policy file server (port 843 by default), or if necessary, on the socket you're opening (for you, port 2222).

A policy file server is a socket which responds to a `<policy-file-request/>` with a valid policy file.  What's happening with your message is likely that it's sending its request and getting something other than a policy file back, hence invalid syntax from port 2222.

There are a lot of resources out there, and a number of questions [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=socket+policy+file).  Here's [one tutorial](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/socket_policy_files.html) from Adobe.

Comment: This was definitely the answer to my question!  Once I programmed my socket to return a my crossdomain.xml file OVER THE SOCKET when it got a "<policy-file-request/>" message, suddenly all Flex's complaints about it vanished.  Thank you!