# actionscript: connect to socket server

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, security, sockets

I am using actionscript to connect to my socket server, but I always got `<policy-file-request/>` sent from actionscript and after that the conneciton is closed. The code in actionscript is:

```
            protected function connect_to_server_btn_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            Security.loadPolicyFile("http://192.168.0.198/crossdomain.xml");
            socket = new Socket();
            socket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, onConnect);
            socket.connect("192.168.0.198", 9999);
        }
```

The content of crossdomain.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

The swf and it's wrapper html are all put under http://192.168.0.198/bin-debug/, and the crossdomain.xml file is loaded by actionscript successfully(thru packet capture tool).

I think supposely I shouldn't get `<policy-file-request/>` if I provided the crossdomain.xml? Thanks in advance!

Comment: oh, can anyone help me to edit it? looks like the crossdomain.xml is invisible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is tutorial how to solve
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/socket_policy_files.html

Flash Player checks for a policy file server (port 843 by default), or if necessary, on the socket you're opening (for you, port 2222).

Also, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181320/help-with-cross-domain-file-for-actionscript-3-socket).

Comment: you can also find some opensource project based on python, which releases this server, and answering with your custom crossdomain file on 843 port. Like this one http://www.webmechs.com/actionscript-3-tutorials/actionscript-echo-server.html You could even find some deb/rpm package.

Comment: Or you can use my Apache 2 module answering requests at the port 843: http://code.google.com/p/mod-socket-policy/source/browse/trunk/