# XMLSocket "Failed to load policy file" error

Tags: flash, xmlsocket

I am trying to use an XMLSocket.swf file, and it is not connecting.  Do I need to open up a port on my server?  I am trying to run this on a dedicated remote Windows 2008 server.

Here is the error from FlashFirebug:

```
OK: Root-level SWF loaded: file:///C|/Users/vcaadmin/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/70vbx4ys.default/extensions/flashfirebug%40o%2Dminds.com/chrome/content/flashfirebug.swf

OK: Root-level SWF loaded: http://speak-tome.com/flash/XMLSocket.swf

OK: Searching for <allow-access-from> in policy files to authorize data loading from resource at xmlsocket://speak-tome.com:9997 by requestor from http://speak-tome.com/flash/XMLSocket.swf

Error: Failed to load policy file from xmlsocket://speak-tome.com:9997

Error: Request for resource at xmlsocket://speak-tome.com:9997 by requestor from http://speak-tome.com/flash/XMLSocket.swf has failed because the server cannot be reached.
```

My crossdomain.xml is saved to the root of the web directory and looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
<site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
<allow-access-from domain="*"/>
<allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="SOAPAction"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Comment: I notice that both ports 843 and 9997 are closed for my domain (speak-tome.com - 72.167.253.16) when I check using a service such as http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/.  Do I need to get these ports open to get the policy file to work?

Answer (score 0):

I think the first part of the answer is that you would need to use an xmlsocket policy server, as noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181320/help-with-cross-domain-file-for-actionscript-3-socket).